# Is using many variables good practice?

Tags: variables, coding-style, declaration

I always tend to declare a new variable every time I have some heavy treatment(e.g. mathematical operation) to store the result within.

Is it a good or a bad practice?

Comment: If it makes the code easier to understand, it's great.

Comment: You should not add unnecessary variables but other than that there is nothing wrong with declaring many variables.

Comment: I'm just afraid it is memory consuming. If not than great.

Comment: It's not memory consuming. It will probably be translated to something entirely different at compile time anyway. Variables are useful for the readability of your code. If adding a variable clears things up, do it. If it is not improving readability, then don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one of my first programs (solving a quadratic equation) had 30 variables and I felt so proud that I managed it lol. However too many variables which are unnecessary will kill the readability big time and you're going to start having troubles.

I'd say it's a double-edged sword. Use too many and you fail, use to little and errors start to happen.

Aim for making it neat so you have minimal troubles locating yourself and figuring out what's happening.

Good luck!
:)